# How can I add the error message to my dataframe when I run through this loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

When I go through this loop in R, I would like to add another column in my data-frame called "store" that tells me what error message is being produced when the loop goes through that specific file. I am already putting all of my necessary calculations in to the dataframe called "Store" but I would also like to add a column for the errors being produced when the loop runs through each file and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
# define working directories
parentdir<-"C:/Users/s2087070/Desktop/PhD/IAH Systematic Review/IAH fitting"# root path to 
main folder
codedir <- paste(parentdir,"/code_1",sep="") # directory containing functions needed for 
fitting
datadir <- paste(parentdir,"/data_1",sep="") # directory containing data files (csv)
resultsdir <- paste(parentdir,"/results_1",sep="") # directory to store results

setwd(datadir)

files<-list.files()
store <-data.frame("Filename"=NA, "pval"=NA,"numpar.full"=NA,"dev"=NA,"p.estim"=NA)
counter<-1

for(file in files){
print(file)
dataname<-strsplit(file,split='[.]')[[1]][1]

library(data.table)

setwd(codedir)
source("func.modelfit_no_confidence.R")  # file containing all required function 
definitions
setwd(datadir)
data.orig <- as.data.table(read.csv(paste(dataname,'.csv',sep='')))

colnames <- names(data.orig)
if(!any(colnames=='inoc.size') || !any(colnames=='num.inf') || !any(colnames=='num.tot')){
stop ("The input data does not contain the necessary columns. Please ensure data contains 
columns inoc.size, num.inf, and num.tot.") 
}

# sort from lowest to highest inoculum size
setkey(data.orig,inoc.size)

# initialize 'data' to original input data
data <- data.orig

# remove any cases where inocsize is zero (i.e. mock-infection controls): cannot estimate 
Pr(infect) from this condition
if(sum(data$inoc.size==0)>0){
data <- data[inoc.size!=0]
warning("Controls with inoculum size zero have been excluded.")
}


if(sum(data$num.inf==data$num.tot)>1){
ind.end <- first(which(data$num.inf==data$num.tot))
warning("Data point(s) at highest inoc.size have been excluded.")
} else{ ind.end <- length(data$num.inf) }

if(sum(data$num.inf==0)>1){
ind.start <- last(which(data$num.inf==0))
warning("Data point(s) at lowest inoc.size have been excluded.")
} else{ ind.start <- 1}

# Take data left after the above ad-hoc removals:
data <- data[ind.start:ind.end]


# set directory to store model fitting results and plots
setwd(resultsdir)

attach(data)

sat.model.fit <- fit.sat(inoc.size,num.inf,num.tot)

IAH.model.fit <- fit.IAH(inoc.size,num.inf,num.tot)

detach(data)


# "saturated" model fitting Pr(infection) separately at each inoc size
logL.sat <- sat.model.fit$logL.tot
numpar.full <- length(data$inoc.size)

# IAH model fitting a single parameter, p = per-capita Pr(infect)
logL.reduc <- IAH.model.fit$logL.tot
numpar.reduc <- 1

# calculate IAH model deviance:
dev <- 2*(logL.sat - logL.reduc) # test statistic
pval <- 1-pchisq(dev, df=numpar.full-numpar.reduc) # chi-squared test


### SAVE RESULTS (from model fitting and comparison) ###
save(data, sat.model.fit, IAH.model.fit, dev, pval, 
file=paste("results_",dataname,".Rdata",sep=""))


### PLOTTING: plot proportion of infected hosts vs. inoculum size - data points and IAH 
model fit ###

library(Hmisc)

# define x-axis (inoc size) range:
Nmin <- min(data$inoc.size)*0.1
Nmax <- max(data$inoc.size)*10
Nvals <- 10^seq(from=log10(Nmin),to=log10(Nmax),by=0.1)

store[counter,] <-c(dataname, pval,numpar.full,dev,IAH.model.fit$p.estim)
print(store)

counter<-counter+1
}

store
```

Comment: You could think about purrr's `possibly()` and `safely()`.

Comment: hey, you can also have a look on the Conditions chapter in the Advanced R book (  https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html) to better understand how you can catch conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Base R, example of error trapping when working in a for loop over some function that can fail. you may need to rewrite your code so that you have a function that performs the actions you want for each result you want to compile.

```
# we will be square rooting a list of numbers, 
# and recording each result in a data.frame and trapping errors

(to_do_list <- list(1,2,3,"a",5))

(num_to_do <- length(to_do_list))

# initialising results container
(results_frame <- data.frame(input=numeric(num_to_do),
                            result=numeric(num_to_do),
                            error_msg=character(num_to_do)))
row <- 1

for (i in to_do_list) {
  try_res <- try(sqrt(i)) # part of the code that can cause an error that we might want to record
  error_msg <-""
  
  if(inherits(try_res,"try-error")){
    error_msg <- substr(toString(try_res),1,40) # dont need to substr, I just wanted simpler output for the example
    try_res <- NA
  }
  results_frame[row,] <- data.frame(input=i,
                                    result=try_res,
                                    error_msg=error_msg)
  row <- row + 1
}
results_frame
```